# Set session in foreach loop is not working

Tags: php, session, input-parameters

Am trying to set a session in foreach loop when users post a form so when they refresh the page the post values won't lost, but the session is not saving.

**My Code**

```
<?php session_start();
if(isset($_POST['EventLookUp'])){
/* city state zipcode country*/
    $EventPostArgs = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
    foreach($EventPostArgs as $pname => $pval){
        $_SESSION[$pname] = htmlentities($pval);
    }
echo $_SESSION['country'];
?>
```

Comment: try to print all session values print_r($_SESSION);

Comment: @SujalPatel thank you is working now, i don't know what happened before